# Ansible does not expand newline and linefeed characters in verbose SSH output

Tags: ssh, terminal, ansible

When debugging an Ansible playbook, I occasionally need to use verbose mode to debug the connection itself, like in this call:

`ansible-playbook -vvvv -i inventories/whatever playbook_under_test.yml`

This will, among the debug info from Ansible itself, also output everything that SSH -vvvv would print. However, on the terminal, all newlines and linefeeds from this SSH debug output are represented by escape sequences, which makes the output a huge and rather unreadable unstructured block of text:

```
<192.168.1.2> (255, b'', b'OpenSSH_8.7p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1q FIPS 5 Jul 2022\r\nd
ebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh
_config line 55: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf depth 0\
r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf\r\
ndebug2: checking match for \'final all\' host 192.168.1.2 originally 192.168
.1.2\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.conf line 3: not matched \'fi
nal\'\r\ndebug2: match not found\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/50-redhat.c
onf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config dept
h 1 (parse only)\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/b
ack-ends/openssh.config\r\ndebug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-curve25519-sha256-,
gss-nistp256-sha256-,gss-group14-sha256-,gss-group16-sha512-,gss-gex-sha1-,gs
s-group14-sha1-,gss-group1-sha1-]\r\ndebug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256
,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2
```

(wrapped at 78 columns for readability here, output is abbreviated and anonymized).

How can I configure my Ansible setup so that those `\r\n` escape sequences are actually printed out as proper linebreaks on my terminal?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Is the node you are targeting a Windows machine?

Comment: This happens for me with Ansible 2.9.27 on Fedora 35, targeting the same client systems. You will possibly need to actually *do* something on the target machine -- gather_facts or wait_for_connection might do.

Comment: First things first: upgrade to a supported version of Ansible, 2.9 has been EOL since the end of last year already.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I configure my Ansible setup so that those \r\n escape sequences are actually printed out as proper linebreaks on my terminal?

Create an ansible.cfg file from the location you run Ansible.

```yaml
>  cat ansible.cfg
[defaults]
stdout_callback = yaml
```

Comment: Great, thanks! Now that I know what to search for, I found the documentation for those callback plugins at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html and, from there, ansible-doc -t callback -l to list them and ansible-doc -t callback <plugin name> to get detailed info on each one. A bit less than intuitive, but hey, at least it's available!

Comment: However, on closer checking, this plugin does reformat error messages but the SSH messages remain formatted as above, unfortunately.

Comment: What's the actual issue? It's quite uncommon to run Ansible so verbose, it shouldn't be required.

Comment: Well, I did have issues with connecting to VMs that were freshly instantiated from VMware templates, so I thought having a deeper look into the actual connection process would be helpful. The issue itself is solved now, but I had to copy the message dump into a text editor and replace all the escape sequences by actual newlines to make sense of it... so I just want to know how to avoid that somehow tedious workaround.

Comment: Once you solved the ssh connection issue, I assume you won't have to use Ansible w verbose that much again...